# Map highlight to change the highlight color dynamically

Tags: php, javascript, jquery-plugins, dictionary

I am using map highlight jquery to highlight a particular area in a map.By using this i can able to highlight a particular area.But my need is to change the highlight color dynamically that means if i click one button the area will be highlighted by red and if i click the second button then the same area will be highlighted by green and simultaneously by the other buttons.This is my question...can any one pls help