# Highlight color change for different condition

Tags: php, jquery, dictionary, highlight

How do I change the area map color for different condition when the area is already highlighted?

This is my code:

```
if(partyname = "Democrat")
{  
    var data = $('#MT').data('maphilight') || {fillColor:'ff0000'};
    data.alwaysOn = !data.alwaysOn;
    $('#MT').data('maphilight', data).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');   
}
 if(partyname = "Republican")
{   
    var data = $('#MT').data('maphilight') || {fillColor:'000000'};
    data.alwaysOn = !data.alwaysOn;
    $('#MT').data('maphilight', data).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');
}
```

I am using `jquery.maphighlight.min.js` jQuery plugin for highlighting the map.

My problem is that the area is highlighted by red color with the first button. If I click the second button, the same area is highlighted but the color cannot be changed (the color should be changed to black).

Comment: Was this question copied from another one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing the highlight color after the area is highlighted with default color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552302/changing-the-highlight-color-after-the-area-is-highlighted-with-default-color)

Comment: OMG [how](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515501/map-highlight-to-change-the-highlight-color-dynamically) [many](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550875/changing-the-highlight-color-after-the-area-is-highlighted) [copies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552302/changing-the-highlight-color-after-the-area-is-highlighted-with-default-color) [again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552842/changing-the-highlight-color-after-the-area-is-highlighted-with-default-color)? Unfortunately i don't have more votes today :(

Comment: Oops, same question asked 4 times by the same user. :(

Comment: @alex: ya it's a same one i need to get a answer for that...but i done a mistake of copy the same question...so now i just need a answer or any suggestion

Comment: @user You should edit your original post, to bump it. Posting the same question multiple times is frowned upon I believe.

Comment: @CF Mitrah : ya it's a same one...but still now i wont get any answer for my question...so i repeately ask the same question

Comment: @alex : ya just now i know about that...and also i am new to this site.So i dont know how to ask the question and how to interact with others

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Re-asking the same question isn't acceptable behavior here.  If you want to draw attention to your question, you will be allowed to [place a bounty on it](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty) after two days.  You can also [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5552842/edit) to add additional information, which may make your question easier to understand and answer.  **NOTE TO OTHERS**:  Please do NOT close this question.  I have closed and merged all others into this one.

Comment: @Will : I understand my fault.Thank you....I am waiting for answer for my question.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, try replacing "colorToHightlight" with colorToHighlight so you call the correct variable that you named earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

Jquery:

```
var colorToHighlight = "black" //default

$("#color_options a").click(function (e)
{
    e.preventDefault(); //stop the anchor tag

    colorToHighlight = $(this).attr("id");
}

/*
    Do the highlight stuff

*/
```

HTML:

```
<div id="color_options">
    <a href="#" id="green">Green</a> - <a href="#" id="red">Red</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the jQuery extension you're talking about but just replace "colorToHighlight" with the variable it uses to select the color to highlight the map section

Answer (score 0):

We used the alt attribute to hold the colour.

HTML:

```
<p><a href="#" class="aToggle" alt="37ee8d">Go GREEN</a></p>
```

JS/JQuery:

```
        $('.aToggle').click(function (e) {
            var data = $('#area1').mouseout().data('maphilight') || {};
            data.fillColor = $(this).attr('alt');
            $('#area1').data('maphilight', data).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');
        });
```

Where "area1" is the map area.